# Bootstrap collapsible is pushing items to the next column

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap's collapsible functionality to have a list of stores with expandable information.

The problem is, when I open one of the collapsibles on the left hand column, it pushes some items into the next column. If I open a collapsible on the right hand column, everything slides properly, but it also adds a space on the left hand column. Please see the following plunker. Resize the screen until there are two rows of collapsibles and then click on one in each row to see the two behaviours:

http://plnkr.co/edit/2SLCQQJetyvM34mrCsHj?p=preview

This is the code I am using:

```
<div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{removeSpaces(x.name, true)}}">
        {{x.name}}
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="{{removeSpaces(x.name, false)}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="store-info col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
        <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
          <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My desired result is to have the collapsible only slide the column that it lives in, and that items do not move onto the next row. Is this possible with Bootstrap's grid system?

Comment: Cannot see the code in the plunker

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Please see updated link. Thanks.

Comment: Now working :) btw I wasn't the one who downvoted... Anyway what exactly is the problem in the left column? You want the collapsible to just collapse over the other elements and not push them down?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I want them to push down, but I don't want the open collapsible to push items into the next column to compensate for the size of the collapsible. For the right container, I don't want the open collapsible to create open space in the left hand container. Please let me know if you need any more clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use two separated columns for your panels. Something like this:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#xname-1">
              xname-1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="xname-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="store-info col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
              <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
                <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#xname-2">
              xname-2
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="xname-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="store-info col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
              <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
                <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#xname-3">
              xname-3
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="xname-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="store-info col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
              <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
                <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#xname-4">
              xname-4
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="xname-4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="store-info col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
              <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
                <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#xname-5">
              xname-5
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="xname-5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="store-info col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
              <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
                <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#xname-6">
              xname-6
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="xname-6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="store-info col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
              <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
              <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
                <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**UPD.** I've improved my Plinker. Now there are no superfluous repetitions in it. But I must warn you that I do not know Angular well.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hj0NF9Vb5ydNIrXLOwPT?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="column in [0,1]">
        <div class="panel-group col-xs-12 stores-container" ng-repeat="x in storeList" ng-if="$index >= ( $parent.$index * storeList.length / 2 ) && $index < ( ( $parent.$index + 1 ) * storeList.length / 2 )">
          <div class="panel panel-default store-wrapper">
            <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{removeSpaces(x.name, true)}}">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a>
                    {{x.name}}
                  </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="{{removeSpaces(x.name, false)}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="store-info col-xs-12" ng-repeat="item in x.stores">
                  <div class="col-xs-6 city">{{item.city}}:</div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6 phone">
                    <a ng-href="tel:{{item.number}}">{{item.number}}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much for saving me from further headache. HTML/CSS is not my strong suit ;-). I'll be sure to give you the bounty when I'm able to do so. Cheers!

Comment: @developthewebz Glab to help. I've improved my Plinker. Now there are no superfluous repetitions in it. But I must warn you that I do not know Angular well. http://plnkr.co/edit/Hj0NF9Vb5ydNIrXLOwPT?p=preview

Comment: It put me on the right track and I was able to integrate the same idea into my own project. It's working perfectly and you even considered mobile, so thank you for that! You are awesome! Have a fantastic rest of your day.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there's one simple solution to this if you want it.

Just put `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after every two `col-xs-12` divs. And it will stop pushing the elements after it to the right.

You can see the example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YE0Zx07AdsKpMj93C3Ep?p=preview).

Note: Remember, put `clear div` after every N collapsible div (it should be the same as the column number)

Comment: Or even simply `.panel-group:nth-of-type(2n+1) { clear: left; }`

Comment: @jackjop Thanks! That solves the first issue, but how can I prevent it from creating white space in the opposite column when the collapsible is opened?